# React Native absolute image file path

Tags: react-native

I am using [React Native Contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts) to get the user's contact list on iOS. For contacts with an image this returns a `thumbnailPath` string which is an absolute path to the contact's image but I can't seem to get it to display in an `<Image>` element.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
renderContact(contact) {
    let imageUri = contact.thumbnailPath ? {uri: 'file://' + contact.thumbnailPath} : null;
    return (
        <View style={styles.contactRow}>
            <Image style={styles.thumbnail} source={imageUri}/>
            <Text>{contact.givenName} {contact.familyName}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Tried both with and without the `file://` protocol but still displays nothing. If I replace the url with a lorempixel url it works so I know that the styling isn't the issue.

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#local-filesystem-images) for images say to use `CameraRoll` for local resources that are outside of `Images.xcassets` but surely you don't need both CameraRoll access and Contact access just to list contacts?

Comment: what does the uri returned by react native contacts look like? `uri` seems to imply a network request https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images you could also try crafting a larger object `{"path":"/Users/react/HelloWorld/contact-img.png","uri":"contact-img.png"}`

Comment: https://github.com/Wraptime/react-native-get-real-path